# how to access property of a nested struct from object of a outer struct

Tags: c#, struct, nested, unmanaged

I have a precompiled struct as follow and unfortunately can not make changes in its definition

```
public struct SYSINFO          // Can not change/update this
    {
        public int ver;

        public struct printer
        {
            public string ver;
            public string serial;
            public string hserial;            
        }
        public struct laminator
        {
            public bool installed;
            public string ver;            
        }
    }
```

I am using this struct as out parameter in below code

```
uint test = smart.GetSystemInfo(out SYSINFO sinew); 
string number=sinew.printer.serial;   //<----Not working sinew doesn't have printer option
```

I need to get value of printer.serial property. I am using C# with .Net Framework 4.6.1. i can not change the struct definition.

Comment: Did you look at sample code at pinvoke? http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/GetSystemInfo.html

Comment: `SYSINFO` doesn't contain a public member called `printer` it simply contains an integer field called `ver`. The nested elements are completely separate types, they are just definitions of other structs that are contained within the struct. You are mixing up type definitions with type members.

Answer (score 0):

There's no instantiation of the inner structs.  There's nothing to access.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a `struct` declaration inside another struct, all you are doing is declaring a type. You have to use the type, e.g. expose a field of that type.

```
public struct SYSINFO          
{
    public struct printerType
    {
        public string ver;
        public string serial;
        public string hserial;            
    }

    public struct laminatorType
    {
        public bool installed;
        public string ver;            
    }

    public int ver;

    public printerType printer;

    public laminatorType laminator;
}
```

Comment: John Thanks for our reply, But its a third party code and i can not change it .It is written to access in c++ and i need to access it by C# code

Comment: Your not understanding.  You need a variable of SYSINFO.printer declared somewhere.  The example you showed only shows the class structure, there's no variable to access.